# Apache CXF (3.1.4) - org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unexpected element

Tags: apache, web-services, cxf, mtom

I'm working on IRS ACA A2A web service client and new to CXF. I keep getting the below exception. What am I doing wrong ?

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unexpected element {urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:irsacabulkrequesttransmitter}ACABulkRequestTransmitter found.   Expected {urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:irsacabulkrequesttransmitter}ACABulkRequestTransmitterResponse.
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.DocLiteralInInterceptor.validatePart(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:280)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:191)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doInterceptStartingAt(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:470)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:772)
```

Comment: I was mixing Interceptors and JAX-WS handlers which was causing this issue. Once, I changed all to Interceptors, issue resolved.